# Condicional IF en consulta SQL

Tags: java, sql, if

Estoy desarrolando una aplicacion java web en NETBEANS y tengo una consulta la cual muestra valores numericos unicamente, cuando ejecuto mi consulta me los muestra en una tabla organizados, todo funciona a la perfeccion.

Lo que quiero hacer son 3 condiciones "IF" con los valores que jala de mi Base de Datos:

- Si los valores son menores a 50 los valores se pinten de color rojo.
- Si los valores son mayores de 50 pero menores de 95 se pinten de naranja.
- Si los valores son mayores de 96 se pinten de color verde.

Es la parte final de mi desarrollo y realmente me ayudaria su ayuda, Muchas gracias.

Les dejo el código de mi consulta abajo.
Los `rs.getString()` son los valores de la consulta.

```
    <%
consulta conexion = new consulta ("jdbc:oracle:thin:@localhost:1521:XE","pasaportes","oppasaportes");
    String consulta = "SELECT  DELEGACION, id_delegacion, CONTRATO   , prerequisitos_tecnologicos, equipamiento, sistema_operacion, privilegios, capacitacion, citas FROM delegaciones";

       ResultSet rs = conexion.ejeSelect(consulta);
         ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
               int col= rsmd.getColumnCount();           
                     for(int k=1;k<=col;k++){          
                %>                                       
                <td><h9> <%= rsmd.getColumnName(k) %></h9></td>
                <%
                                }      
                %>                               
            </tr>         

            <%
             while(rs.next()){
            %>
            <tr> 
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(1) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(2) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(3) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(4) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(5) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(6) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(7) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(8) %></h6> </td>
                <td><h6><%= rs.getString(9) %></h6> </td>
            </tr>
            <%
                       }
            %>
```

Comment: Que se pinte la celda o la fila?

Comment: Las celdas. @JorgeArturoJuarez

Comment: Por favor aclara tus conceptos y no los mezcles. SQL es para persistencia/consulta de datos. El color que uses para pintar un número es parte de la interfaz de usuario. ¿¿¿Importa mucho para decidir el color si el dato viene de una consulta SQL, un fichero o una llamada a un webservice??? Una vez aclarado este punto, la pregunta se responde por sí misma.

Comment: Disculpa por no ser claro, es que soy algo nuevo y no sabia como darme a entender. @SJuan76

Comment: Tal vez quieras revisar [*How to avoid Java code in JSP files?*](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3177733/how-to-avoid-java-code-in-jsp-files) y, opcionalmente, [*Top 5 reasons that JSP scriptlets suck*](http://www.theserverside.com/feature/Top-5-reasons-that-JSP-scriptlets-suck).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

creo que no es muy bueno utilizar código de java en las vistas sino mas bien enviar objetos a las vistas y manejarlos mediante JSTL. Pero me basaré en el código que ya haz planteado en tu pregunta.

```
 while(rs.next()){

         String color = "";

         //Fila 1
         if(rs.getInt(1) < 50){
             color = "style='background-color:red'";
         }else if ((rs.getInt(1) >= 50) && (rs.getInt(1) < 95)){
             color = "style='background-color:orange'";
         }else if(rs.getInt(1) >= 95){
             color = "style='background-color:green'";
         }

         %>
         <td <%= color %> ><h6><%= rs.getString(1) %></h6> </td>
         <%

         //Fila 2
         if(rs.getInt(2) < 50){
             color = "style='background-color:red'";
         }else if ((rs.getInt(2) >= 50) && (rs.getInt(2) <= 95)){
             color = "style='background-color:orange'";
         }else if(rs.getInt(2) > 95){
             color = "style='background-color:green'";
         }

         %>
         <td <%= color %> ><h6><%= rs.getString(2) %></h6> </td>
         <%

         //etc. etc. Así con cada fila que siga o con la que tu quieras
}
```

Asumo que lo que quieres hacer es fila a fila, ahí decide tu cuales son las filas que te interesan pintar. Ojo que para hacer comparaciones numéricas debes obtener el dato como "getInt" no como "getString".

Saludos!

Comment: Muchísimas Gracias, gracias por tomarte de tu tiempo para ayudarme, lo agradezco infinitamente!!

Answer (score 3):

```
seria algo asi

    <%
if(rs.getInt(1)<50){
%>
         <td style="background-color:red;"><h6><%= rs.getString(1) %></h6> </td>
    <%
}else if (rs.getInt(1)<95){
%>
         <td style="background-color:orange;"><h6><%= rs.getString(1) %></h6> </td>
    <%
}else{
%>
         <td style="background-color:green;"><h6><%= rs.getString(1) %></h6> </td>
    <%
}
%>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, me sirvió de mucho!!! mil gracias en verdad!